# training argument error issue in GaussianNoise

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am facing issue while generating noise in mnist dataset using GaussianNoise from tensorflow keras.

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GaussianNoise
sample = GaussianNoise(0.15)
sample(X_test[0:2],training=True )
```

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "gaussian_noise_7" (type GaussianNoise).

Cannot convert 0.0 to EagerTensor of dtype uint8

Call arguments received:
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(2, 28, 28), dtype=uint8)
• training=True

**When I removed the training then  error is eliminated but image is as such without any noise as function is inferring image as such without adding any noise.**

Please help in sorting this issue.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a bit confusing how the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/gaussian_noise/) of the GaussianNoise layer deals with the boolean call parameter `training`. As this layer is intended to be a preprocessing layer (e.g. augmentation), it will only be active at training time. Meaning that when you are inferring with a trained model, it won't add noise to your input.

I would suggest using such a layer only at defining the model if you really need it as preprocessing. [Here](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/) you can find info about using Keras layers as preprocessing. If you just want to add noise to an image, use [openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html).

Comment: Quite helpful and insightful. Thanks a lot Nicolas !!!